# SAS Group by numerical value or convert to char

Tags: sas

I have the following data:

```
data have;
       input username $  betdate : datetime. customerCode;
       dateOnly = datepart(betdate) ;
       format betdate DATETIME.;
       format dateOnly ddmmyy8.;
       datalines; 
        player1 12NOV2008:12:04:01 1
        player1 04NOV2008:09:03:44 10
        player2 07NOV2008:07:03:33 1 
        player2 05NOV2008:09:00:00 0.5 
        player3 05NOV2008:09:05:00 1
        player2 07NOV2008:14:03:33 1 
        player1 05NOV2008:09:00:05 20
        player2 07NOV2008:16:03:33 1 
        player2 07NOV2008:18:03:33 1 
        player2 09NOV2008:10:05:10 0.7
        player3 15NOV2008:15:05:33 10 
        player3 15NOV2008:15:05:33 1
        player2 15NOV2008:15:05:33 0.1
    run;
    PROC PRINT; RUN;
```

When I run the following, I don't get distinct, collapsed entries for customerCode when I group by it because it is numeric, I presume.

```
    proc sql;
         select username, customerCode from have group by 1,2;
    quit;
```

How can I do this? I want to get a history of all the customer codes that have been assigned to a customer (i.e as they change), rather than an entry for each numeric value for customerCode. I haven't been able to convert the variable to a char value so that the grouping works:

```
proc sql;
     create table want as 
     select * from have, customerCode FORMAT $10. as code;
```

quit;

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Is `create table have as select distinct username, customercode from have;` what you want? Alternately, what about `proc sort data=want(keep = username customercode) nodups out=have; by username customercode; run;`? (Should do the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting distinct entries because it is ignoring your `group by`, because you didn't ask for any summary functions.  SAS does not permit `group by` without a summary function (ie, `sum(something)` or `count(something)` or whatever), it converts it to `order by`.  There's no explicit reason numeric wouldn't work for grouping.

This is noted in the log with a `NOTE`, by the way.

You can use `distinct`, as you suggested in the comments:

```
proc sql;
select distinct username, customercode from have;
quit;
```

That will give you a list of all username/customercode combinations.

If you wanted to format it, you have to remove the $ - the $ in format does not mean "make this a character", which is what all formats do; it means "the original value pre-format was a character value".

```
proc sql;
     create table want as 
     select distinct username, customercode format=10. from have;
quit;
```

This won't quite work as expected, because the format is applied *after* the distinct is processed (and the post-decimal portion still exists, just under the hood).  However, you can do:

```
proc sql;
     create table want as 
     select distinct username, put(customercode,10.) from have;
quit;
```

Or you could use ROUND or something else to keep it numeric.

Comment: I think your question is insufficiently specified.  DISTINCT certainly does work, and does what I would expect: gives every unique combination of username/customercode.

Comment: Perhaps clarify what your intended results are in your question -ie, a `want` dataset.  And/or clarify what `customerCode` means.